# VSIX - Know when a snippet is being inserted

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is it possible to know when a snippet is being inserted into a document? I would like to block all automatic changes that our plugin is doing in the ITextBuffer, while the user is navigating through and filling in all fields in a snippet. Because otherwise the snippet insertion ends automatically.

We've already looked at IVsExpansionManager, WindowEvents, DocumentEvents, TextEditorEvents, etc. But they all don't seem to contain the events that we need.

Comment: Maybe you can check if [IVsExpansionClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivsexpansionclient?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#remarks) interface helps.

Comment: Seems indeed exactly what I need. But how do I get the object that implements the interface?

Comment: It seems you need to create your own class to implement this interface. Try to get the IVsExpansionClient implementation by using the ITextView.  See Caillen's answer from this [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/806c6a07-3408-44e9-b24f-68a9acf4e2e6/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-ivsexpansionclient-in-vspackage?forum=vsx). Hope it helps.

Comment: But then I probably already need to know that a snippet is being inserted, before I can retrieve that implementation? In other words, what will be the trigger to get the IVsExpansionClient object from ITextView?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure. There's not enough information about the usage of this api online :( And I haven't created an extension which is related to Snippet topic.

Comment: Is there a property that indicates if a snippet session is currently active? Maybe we could use that one, instead of events.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is negative, I check the related interfaces again with no luck to find the property you need. Maybe it's not supported for now,